# Redirect loop from two domain using the same .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

How our FTP was setup, the root level is Website #1.  Website #2 has it's own directory folder inside that root.

Both websites refer to the same *.htaccess*.

If I do `Redirect 301 /example/ http://www.website2.com/example/`, there will be a redirect loop.

It will redirect `http://www.website1.com/example/` to `http://www.website2.com/example/`.

Then also redirect `http://www.website2.com/example/` to `http://www.website2.com/example/`
(which creates the redirect loop)

What I want is to somehow only redirect `http://www.website1.com/example/` to `http://www.website2.com/example/` without creating the redirect loop.

NOTE: I do NOT want every webpage on Website#1 to redirect to Website#2.  Just that specific URL to the new URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use mod_rewrite (as opposed to a mod_alias `Redirect`) and check the `HTTP_HOST` server variable (which tells you which site has been accessed). Something like the following at the top of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)$ http://www.website2.com/example/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change the `302` (temporary) to a `301` (permanent) redirect if you need a permanent redirect, but only after you have tested to make sure it's working OK. (`301` redirects are cached by the browser so can make testing problematic - unless you test with the browser cache disabled.)

This redirects `/example/<something>` to `http://www.website2.com/example/<something>`, in much the same way as the original `Redirect` directive would do (which is *prefix* matching).

---

**UPDATE:** To redirect just the homepage, ie. `http://www.website1.com/` to `http://www.website2.com/`, you can use something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.website2.com/ [R=302,L]
```

Note the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^$` - this matches the empty URL (ie. the homepage only). (Note that the URL matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is less the directory-prefix.)

Comment: 1 more question: How do I redirect; just the homepage.  Website1 homepage, to Website2 homepage?  I tried doing the same way, but it is redirecting everything, to the equivalent version.... Do I need to wrap it in quotes or something? So it's exact match redirect?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I assume there's no `example` subdirectory this time - literally just the document root - one domain to the other.